# cronjob not redirecting output of command when used with option

Tags: cron, linux-audit

I'm not able to redirect output of command into a file when ran with cronjob

```
[root@mail /]# crontab -l  
*/1   *   *     *   *    /sbin/ausearch -i  >  /rummy

[root@mail /]# cat /rummy
```

It's weird that when I dont give `-i` option , I'm able to redirect it very well.

```
[root@mail /]# crontab -l  
*/1 *   *   *   *   /sbin/ausearch > /rummy

[root@mail /]# cat /rummy  
usage: ausearch [options]
    -a,--event <Audit event id> search based on audit event id  
    --arch <CPU>            search based on the CPU architecture  
    -c,--comm  <Comm name>      search based on command line name  
    -  
    -  
    -
```

It there any syntax error or I'm missing here something?

Note - "ausearch -i" fetches me below output on terminal and on redirecting output to file , it redirects it as it is.

```
    [root@server ~]# ausearch -i  
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(05/22/2017 11:14:10.391:6858) : auditd                     start, ver=2.4.5 format=raw kernel=2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 auid=unset pid=1319 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=success 
----
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(05/22/2017 11:14:10.519:5) : audit_backlog_limit=320 old=64 auid=unset ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:auditctl_t:s0 res=yes 
----
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(05/22/2017 11:20:01.108:6) : user pid=2073 uid=root auid=unset ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct=root exe=/usr/sbin/crond hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success' 
----
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(05/22/2017 11:20:01.108:7) : user pid=2073 uid=root auid=unset ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct=root exe=/usr/sbin/crond hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success' 
----
type=LOGIN msg=audit(05/22/2017 11:20:01.119:8) : pid=2073 uid=root subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 old auid=unset new auid=root old ses=unset new ses=1 
----
```

Comment: Just for grins, change the line in cron to `*/1   *   *     *   *    /sbin/ausearch -i  >  /rummy 2>&1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command does not produce output, but runs ok.

You can see this because the file `rummy` got created.

The `ausearch` utility [seems to expect a "search criteria"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Searching_the_Audit_Log_Files.html), and the empty output could be due to you not providing one.

See the `ausearch` manual on your system for further information.

---

After a bit of reading of the `ausearch` manual, I found the following:

> `--input-logs`
>   Use the log file location from `auditd.conf` as input for searching. **This is needed if you are using `ausearch` from a cron job.**

Doing some Googling confirms that this indeed may be the issue. [One email describes the problem](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2008-November/msg00063.html):

> You need to use the `--input-logs` option. If `ausearch` sees stdin as a pipe, it 
>   assumes that is where it gets its data from. The input logs option tells it 
>   to ignore the fact that stdin is a pipe and process the logs. `Aureport` has 
>   the same problem and option to fix it.
>
> This was fixed in the 1.6.7 general release and backported to the 1.6.5 RHEL5 
>   release.

There also seems to be users who does not solve this by using `--input-logs`, but it's not clear what else may be wrong as there are never any followups from them.

Comment: The "ausearch -i" output is not empty and "ausearch -i > /file" runs as expected on terminal. Here note that "-i,--interpret" interpret results to be human readable and hences it does not require any argument and capture output into file using redirection on terminal , but same is not happening using cronjob

Comment: @JackWatson You should update the question with the expected output (that which you get when running `ausearch -i` on the command line).

Comment: modified the query , let me know if I need to clear more anything :)

Comment: @JackWatson Answer updated.

Comment: its working now as you suggested with --input-logs option :) , thanks dude!